# VBScript: Lotus Notes autosave attachments with specific extension

Tags: vbscript, lotus, attachment, autosave

Early, I posted theme "Groovy: autosave attachment with specific extension from Lotus Notes", but couldn't find any solution, so i found different vbscripts and make own. Its works, but now i have a problem: letter doesn't delete after as script autosave attach. I see error: "All objects must be from the same session". I will be grateful for any idea.

```
Dim Session 
Dim Maildb 
Dim vw 
Dim doc 
Dim Item 
Dim x 
Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 
Call Session.Initialize("password") 
Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("SERVER", "mail.nsf") 
If Not Maildb.IsOpen = True Then 
Call Maildb.Open 
End If 
Set vw = Maildb.GetView("($inbox)") 
With vw 
x = 0 
ReDim LmailID(x) 
ReDim HasAttach(x) 
Set doc = .GetFirstDocument 
Set Item = doc.GetFirstItem("Body") 
Do 
If Item.Type = RICHTEXT Then  -  here i try take unread message and it doesnt work
fileNames = Session.Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc) 
For Each Filename In fileNames 
If Filename <> "" Then 
If Right(Filename, 3) = "bch" Then
Call doc.Save( False, True, True )
Set NotesEmbeddedObject = doc.GetAttachment(Filename) 
NotesEmbeddedObject.ExtractFile ("C:\" + Filename) 
Set reply = doc.CreateReplyMessage( False )
Call reply.replaceItemValue("Subject", "DONE" + subject)
Call reply.Send( False )
Set nextDoc = .GetNextDocument(doc)
Set doc = nextDoc
End If 
End If 
Next 
End If
x = x + 1 
ReDim Preserve LmailID(x) 
Set doc = .GetNextDocument(doc) 
Wscript.Sleep 500 
Loop Until doc Is Nothing 
End With 
Set Session = Nothing 
Set vw = Nothing 
Set doc = Nothing 
Set Item = Nothing 
Set Maildb = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:
Inside the loop you are using `.GetFirstDocument`. Move that outside the loop (outside `With vw`) and then use `.GetNextDocument(doc)` inside the loop (as you are already doing).

Also, you are calling `doc.Remove(True)` and then later trying to fetch the next document by refering to the `doc` instance that you just deleted. To fix this, you can add another document instance such as `nextDoc` and then use this as a temporary document while you delete the `doc` instance:

Before you delete doc:

```
Set nextDoc = .GetNextDocument(doc)
```

After you have deleted doc:

```
Set doc = nextDoc
```

Comment: thanks! great! that's work for me! so, how i can mark letter as read and sent autoreply, if i dont want remove letter? call doc.MarkRead() is not work in VBScript

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method: "MarkRead"

Comment: markRead and markUnread are now methods in Lotusscript from Notes 8. What version of Notes are you running?

Comment: I used Call doc.Save( False, True, True ) in code and its help.

Comment: In script I did autoreply message after as i save attachment, but i still have another problem: script saves attachments with .bch extension from all messages in Inbox, but i need save attachments only from unread messages. I used If Item.Type = RICHTEXT in code, but it doesnt work